# Leading Zero CSV Disappearing

Tags: php, excel, export-to-csv, xlsx

I have converted an xlsx to CSV and changed the column data format to 'text' in the wizard as suggested on so many articles on the internet.

However now that I have saved the CSV and on re-open, the zero's have now disappeared again?

Can anyone help me out with this?

Many Thanks

Comment: When you reopen the csv, does it still think those columns are text?

Answer (score 0):

*CSV is dumb, it's mostly used for data exchange as it's in ASCII format and can be handled by most systems.*

If CSV file is directly opened using Excel, Excel will always ignore leading 0 as it does not have any knowledge about the column being text. You will have to import CSV data and then define the column as text, then save it as a **Excel document (not CSV)**.

If you want to preserve columns definition, cell data types then you should directly use Excel (e.g. xls, xlsx).